# get specific cell value in csv file using powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell, don't get to use this often.
I need to output the value of cell A5 from a csv file using powershell

my file -

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
---- ---- ---- ----
1002 1005 1006 1007
```

need value in the A1 cell i.e 1002.selection should be done by the cell numbers.

```
$a = @(Import-CSV filepath.csv)
$a[1].(col1)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Import the CSV to your variable

```
$a = Import-CSV filepath.csv
```

Then grab the first row `$a[0]` and use `.` notation to get the column you want. Note that the first row of data is `0` because powershell converts the CSV to an object, seperating the headers and data.

```
$a[0].col1
```

If you don't need any other values from the CSV, then you can forego the variable assignment and trim it down to:

```
(Import-CSV filepath.csv)[0].col1
```

Answer (score 2):

Row 1, Column 1 (A1)

```
$a[0].psobject.properties.value[0]
```

Row 1, Column 5 (A5)

```
$a[0].psobject.properties.value[4]
```