# Extract data from a CSV using powershell and reformat

Tags: powershell, csv

I have data in cell A2 of a CSV file (no headers) that looks like this:  RPT DATE :07/20/23

How can I use PowerShell to read this cell from the file, strip out all except the date value and reformat it to look like: YY-MM-DD

I don't need to read any other data out of the file and there are no headers but there is other data in the first row of the file.  I'm not able to modify the source CSV.

I've played with variations of the examples here with no luck:  [get specific cell value in csv file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433562/get-specific-cell-value-in-csv-file-using-powershell)

This returns "WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers." but no actual value.

Comment: Please post the exact code that generates the warning :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get @RarikmilkraiSouza script working but it did help me figure it out where I needed to go.  This is what I ended up with and it does what I need:

```
# Define the path to the CSV file and dummy header name
$csvFilePath = "C:\testfile.csv"
$headerName = "ColumnA"

# Import the CSV file with the dummy header

$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -Header $headerName

# Get the value from cell A2

$value = $data[1].'ColumnA'

# Extract the date from the value and reformat to YY-MM-DD

$rptdate = $value -replace 'RPT Date :(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})','$3-$1-$2'
$formattedDate = "20" + $rptdate

# Output the result

Write-Output $formattedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Import-Csv cmdlet along with the -Header parameter to specify header names. Since your CSV file doesn't have headers, you can provide dummy header names. Then, you can access the cell value by referencing the corresponding header and row.

Here's how you can do it:

```
# Define the path to the CSV file and dummy header name
$csvFilePath = "path\to\your\file.csv"
$headerName = "Header"

# Import the CSV file with the dummy header

$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -Header $headerName

# Get the value from cell A2

$value = $data | Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Name -eq 
$headerName } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $headerName

# Extract the date from the value (assuming it's always at the end of the string)

$date = $value.Substring($value.LastIndexOf(":") + 2).Trim()

# Reformat the date to YY-MM-DD

$formattedDate = Get-Date $date -Format "yy-MM-dd"


# Output the result

Write-Output $formattedDate
```

Comment: Is this from ChatGPT?

Comment: No, I did something similar a few months ago.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction